# declaring a friend template function

Tags: c++, templates, friend, accelerated-c++

This question is based on partially on exercise 15-4 in *Accelerated C++* [1] and the code in that book. I want to declare the `myclone` function as a friend of a class so that it has access to private members. The `myclone` function is declared as a template, but I don't want to give all possible functions access to the private members, only those associated with that class.

```
class A{
    template <class T>
    friend T* myclone(const T*);

    A* clone() const {return new A(*this);}
}
```

some other file:

```
template <class T>
T* myclone(const T* t) {return t->clone();}
```

Another hypothetical `myclone` function could call the `clone` method of an `A` object, but I want to restrict the private access to `A* myclone(const A*)`. Is there a way to do this or am I overthinking it, and this situation would never occur in practice? Should I use a template specialization?

[1] Koenig, A., & Moo, B. E. (2000). *Accelerated C++ Practical Programming by Example*. Pearson.

Comment: Also why doesn't the obvious ```friend A* myclone(const A*);``` work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix whatever is missing.

Comment: @user1390010 Class A is not a template class. Why is the friend function  a template function?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give a friend access to only some of your private parts. It's an all or nothing thing.

`friend A* myclone(const A*);` doesn't work because there is no such function. The template isn't that function, nor any of its specialization is. If you want to befriend a particular specialization, just say so:

```
template <class T> T* myclone(const T*); // needs to be declared first

class A {
   friend A* myclone<A>(const A*);
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, the missing ```<A>``` was the issue, just didn't interpret the error message properly.